# GetSelectedItem/value from a AutoCompleteTextView [Not Working]

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

i have been trying to get a selectedItem from one of my AutoCompleteTextView(sp_Especie) and pass it to a 
string variable so i can use it in if´s conditions in the other one(sp_Raza) and had no success.

Heres my code:

```
final ArrayList Perros = new ArrayList();

 String[] datos = new String[]{"Perro", "Gato"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CrearPost.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, datos);
        sp_Especie.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp_Especie.setThreshold(1);


        sp_Raza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AutoCompleteTextView sp_Especie = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.sp_Especie);
                String text = sp_Especie.toString();
                System.out.println("COMES DATA " + text);




 if(text=="Perro"){
                    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                    client.get("domain+php", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

                            if(statusCode==200){
                                try {

                                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));

                                    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                        System.out.println("COMES DATA " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Nombre"));
                                        Perros.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Nombre"));

                                    }



                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                        }
                    });

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CrearPost.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Perros);
                    sp_Raza.setAdapter(adapter);
                    sp_Raza.setThreshold(1);

                }


            }

        });
```

i have checked the logcat and it seems that the text doesnt give anything back. But im new to AutoCompleteTextViews so i dont know what method i could use to solve this problem.

Any help would be highly apreciated

Comment: `if(text=="Perro"){` use equals not `==`

Comment: you mean "equals" instead of "==" cause i tried it and it didnt work

Comment: show the complete code

Comment: Just added the rest of the code, although i dont think its going to be much more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a text from `AutoCompleteTextView` you should use

```
String text = sp_Especie.getText().toString();
```

instead of

```
String text = sp_Especie.toString();
```

Your code will be

```
sp_Raza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AutoCompleteTextView sp_Especie = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.sp_Especie);
                String text = sp_Especie.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("COMES DATA " + text);

                if ("Perro".equals(text)) {
                    // TODO: Write your code here
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much this was what i was looking for!

Comment: I dont know if you can help me with this, but it seems i have to clic twice on the autocompletetextview, could there be a problem with the oncliclistener View and onclick view ?

Comment: What does 'I have to click twice on AutoCompleteText' mean?

Comment: Im sorry for not being clear, the problem is when i was running my app and touched the box (Where my autocompletetextview is) it didnt load, i had to tap out and click again, and only then it loaded all the data. 
I changed the onclicklistener to on touchlistener but i still have to click twice for the data to load

Comment: Can you update current code where you have encounted that problem?